What is the proper way to add extra data over push context with Serilog
I would like to log an extra data with an active log context but I have to use different methods:
For example, I am trying to log web api requests with following settings:
On Program.cs at the top:
Log.Logger = new Serilog.LoggerConfiguration()
            .CreateBootstrapLogger();

On service registration:
 services.AddHttpContextAccessor();


services.AddHttpLogging(o =>
{
    o.CombineLogs = true;.
    o.LoggingFields = HttpLoggingFields.All;   
    o.ResponseHeaders.Remove("Content-Type");
    o.ResponseHeaders.Remove("Accept");
    o.RequestHeaders.Remove("Content-Type");
    o.RequestHeaders.Remove("Accept");
    o.RequestBodyLogLimit = 8096;
    o.ResponseBodyLogLimit = 8096;
});

services.AddHttpLoggingInterceptor<SampleHttpLoggingInterceptor>();


var columnOptions = new ColumnOptions
{
    AdditionalDataColumns = new List<DataColumn>
    {
        new DataColumn("CorrelationId", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("TraceId", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("SpanId", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("ChannelId", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("RequestPath", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("Duration", typeof(decimal)),
        new DataColumn("SourceContext", typeof(string)),
    }
};

//columnOptions.Properties.ExcludeAdditionalProperties = true;
//columnOptions.LogEvent.ExcludeAdditionalProperties = true;            
//columnOptions.Store.Remove(StandardColumn.MessageTemplate);
// we don't need XML data
columnOptions.Store.Remove(StandardColumn.Properties);


services.AddSerilog((services, lc) => lc
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
    .ReadFrom.Services(services)

    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    //.MinimumLevel.Override("System.Net.Http.HttpClient", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("System.Net.Http.HttpClient.X", LogEventLevel.Warning) //Temp
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Polly", LogEventLevel.Warning) //express policies such as Retry, Timeout...
    //Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware > Warning

    .Enrich.FromLogContext()

    //.Enrich.WithProperty("MyTraceId", string.Empty)
    //.Enrich.WithProperty("SourceContext", string.Empty)
    //.Enrich.WithProperty("TraceId", string.Empty)
    //.Enrich.WithProperty("SpanId", string.Empty)
    .Enrich.WithProperty("ChannelId", string.Empty)
    .Enrich.WithProperty("Duration", string.Empty)
    .Enrich.WithClientIp()
    //.Enrich.WithCorrelationId() 
    .Enrich.WithCorrelationId("CorrelationIdHeader", addValueIfHeaderAbsence: true)                
    .Enrich.WithSpan()

    .WriteTo.Conditional(
        _ => isDeveloment,
            wt => wt.Console(theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Code          
        )
    )
    
    .WriteTo.Oracle(cfg =>
        cfg.WithSettings(
                "User Id=...", 
                tableSpaceAndTableName: "LogTable",
                tableSpaceAndFunctionName: string.Empty, columnOptions: columnOptions                            
            )
            .UseBurstBatch() //.UsePeriodicBatch(1)                        
            .CreateSink(), 
            restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information
        )
     );


On using services:
app.UseHttpLogging();

app.UseSerilogRequestLogging(options =>
{
       options.IncludeQueryInRequestPath = true;
});

With the settings above I can log following lines (except channelId):

To be able to add channelId, which is a custom column, I need to add following lines on my controller action, otherwise I got null value:
_diagnosticContext.Set("ChannelId", request.Channel); //if SourceContex is "Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware"
LogContext.PushProperty("ChannelId", request.Channel); //if SourceContext general or HttpClient     
HttpContext.Items.Add("CustomKey_ChannelId", request.Channel); //if SourceContext is Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpLogging.HttpLoggingMiddleware

For the HttpLoggingMiddleware, I use Interceptor to add data to log context:
private void EnrichResponse(HttpLoggingInterceptorContext logContext)
{
    var list = logContext.HttpContext.Items.Where(w => w.Key.ToString().StartsWith("CustomKey_")).ToList();
    if (list.Count > 0)
        logContext.AddParameter(list[0].Key.ToString().Replace("CustomKey_", ""), list[0].Value.ToString());


I shouldn't need to use different methods to push custom data to log context for different SourceContext. Either there is a single way and I can't find it or there is a structural problem.
Is there a proper way to do it?
I am hesitant especially using interceptor.
